# Discrete signed distance

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a scalar field $\phi (x,y,z)$ numerically defined for nodes of regular cubic grid in 3D.

How to compute another scalar field defined over the same grid, containing signed distance between grid nodes and $\phi=0$ isosurface of the first scalar field?